# Elasticsearch aggregation of aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, elasticsearch-2.0

I'd like to know if there is a way to do something akin to [bucket_selector](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html) but testing based on a key match instead of a numeric metric.

To give a bit more context, here is my use case:

data sample:

```
[
  {
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2017-04-27T04:28:23.589Z",
    "type": "json",
    "headers": {
      "message": {
        "type": "requestactivation"
      }
    },
    "id": "668"
  },
  {
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2017-04-27T04:32:23.589Z",
    "type": "json",
    "headers": {
      "message": {
        "type": "requestactivation"
      }
    },
    "id": "669"
  },
  {
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2017-04-27T04:30:00.802Z",
    "type": "json",
    "headers": {
      "message": {
        "type": "activationrequested"
      }
    },
    "id": "668"
  }
]
```

I'd like to retrieve all ids where the last event is of type `requestactivation`.

I already have an aggregation that retrieves the last event type per id, 
but I haven't figured out how to filter buckets based on the key

Here is the query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "id"
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "headers.message.type": [
              "requestactivation",
              "activationrequested"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id",
        "size": 10000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest": {
          "max": {
            "field": "@timestamp"
          }
        },
        "hmtype": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "headers.message.type",
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a result sample:

```
{
  "took": 5,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 3,
    "successful": 3,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "id": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 3,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 46,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "986",
          "doc_count": 4,
          "hmtype": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 2,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "activationrequested",
                "doc_count": 2
              }
            ]
          },
          "latest": {
            "value": 1493238253603,
            "value_as_string": "2017-04-26T20:24:13.603Z"
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "967",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "hmtype": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 1,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "requestactivation",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          },
          "latest": {
            "value": 1493191161242,
            "value_as_string": "2017-04-26T07:19:21.242Z"
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "554",
          "doc_count": 7,
          "hmtype": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 5,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "requestactivation",
                "doc_count": 5
              }
            ]
          },
          "latest": {
            "value": 1493200196871,
            "value_as_string": "2017-04-26T09:49:56.871Z"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

*All mappings are not analyzed (keyword).*

Goal would be to reduce results to only the ones where key in bucket is "requestactivation".

The doc count cannot be used as activationrequest can appear more than once for an id.

Only started delving in aggregations recently, so apologies if question seems obvious, examples around didn't seem to match this specific logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `include` used in a `terms` aggregation to "filter" the values included in the terms to only that relevant for the request:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "id"
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "headers.message.type": [
              "requestactivation",
              "activationrequested"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id",
        "size": 10000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest": {
          "max": {
            "field": "@timestamp"
          }
        },
        "hmtype": {
          "filter": {
            "terms": {
              "headers.message.type": [
                "requestactivation",
                "activationrequested"
              ]
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "count_types": {
              "cardinality": {
                "field": "headers.message.type"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "filter_buckets": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "totalTypes":"hmtype > count_types"
            },
            "script": "params.totalTypes == 2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but testing out the proposed include I end up with all ids which have  events "activationrequested" (from your example, I actually am looking for the "requestactivation"), this whether the id has the other type of events or not.

Comment: My bad, it should be `"include": "requestactivation"`... but I have the feeling there are some restrictions on the way.

Comment: But the include basically acts the same way as if I had filtered out the activationrequested **events** in the query (as I do not care about the query hits per say). while i'd like to filter out the **ids** for which an activationrequested was received.

Comment: Not following. What's the use case? You want to see what ids have been acivated? And there can be multiple requests and multiple approvals? Or at least one request and 1 (exactly one) approval?

Comment: indeed, I want to see which ids have been activated. there can be multiple requests and multiple approvals, I'd be happy in this specific case to filter out any id where approval(s) have been received, whichever the count. I've tried out other queries, for example one without max aggregation, and increasing the hmtype terms aggregation size to 2, but haven't figured out a way to filter out the resulting buckets based on the presence of activationrequested events.

Comment: There must be a request before an approval is given, right? I mean an approval needs to correspond to at least one request.

Comment: yes. Data is basically application logs, and application has a log for each requestactivation, then also logs when she gets a confirmation (activationrequested).

Comment: Thanks so much, result is exactly what I wanted. only change needed is `"script": "totalTypes == 1"` - need the ones missing the activationrequested event. and `param.` caused an error, guess it's painless vs groovy issue (still using ES 2.x for the moment).

Comment: Yes. I assumed ES 5 and Painless.